# How to make child div elements affected by div css rules?

Tags: css, html

I have an html which has a main div.

```
<div id="main_container">
```

in it, I have a table, which each row has a button in it:

```
  <tr>
    <td>open2</td>
    <td>CPI</td>
    ...
    <td class="left_border">
        <button>x</button>
    </td>
    <td class="left_border">
        <button>p</button>
    </td>
    <td class="left_border">
        <button>k</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a css rule applied on the div:

```
#main_container {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    border: solid 3px rgba(78, 70, 70, 0.81);    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This rule doesn't seem to apply on the buttons' font-size.
What am I missing here?

Here is a fiddle with the full html + css.

http://jsfiddle.net/9YZuw/11/

Note: I have updated the fiddle so now there is no specific css rule for the button, however its font size is still not derived from its parent div.

Thanks

Comment: Take a minute to format your code before pasting...

Comment: In the given fiddle you are specifically giving style to button. You have defined font-size:8px for buttons. That is why it is not affected by style of parent div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9YZuw/3/

Comment: you can see the the button' font-size is not dependent at the div's

Answer (score 2):

it is because the button-element (along with input, select and textarea) does not inherit certain attributes, and font-size is one of them.

this css will sort it out:

```
button{font-size:inherit;}
```

Comment: Thanks !! At last, one person who gave a correct answer while the others just gave an answer without even testing it.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#main_container {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    border: solid 3px rgba(78, 70, 70, 0.81);    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Remove this css or remove font property here**

```
button {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and also try using em for font size..

Comment: @omar bach,there are n number of tricks and possibilities to make things done in designing and programming.U are satisfied with one...

Comment: I have no problem with several alternatives for a solution, it is just that what you suggested doesn't work.